# Custom slugs with dates & IDs on Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, slug

Trying to do something with the rewrite argument on custom post types.

I'm after 2 different things here for 2 different custom post types.

1: Slugs which look like this

```
post-name-year-month-day
```

So the URL will be something like

```
.com/post-type-1-slug/post-name-year-month-day
```

2: More or less the same but with the ID

```
post-name-id
```

So the URL will be something like

```
.com/post-type-2-slug/post-name-id
```

I'm sure this is pretty easy to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's not hard to do that.

1. Just register your post type and enable rewriting for that post type, i.e. set [`rewrite`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#rewrite) to `true`.
2. Once registered, modify its permalink structure like so:

   ```php
   global $wp_rewrite;
   $wp_rewrite->extra_permastructs['<post type>']['struct'] = '<your structure here>';
   ```
3. Use the [`post_type_link` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/) to replace [rewrite tags like `%post_id%`](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/customize-permalinks/#structure-tags-1) in the permalink URL.

   If you need to use *custom rewrite tags* like `%post_date%` in the permalink structure, you can add the custom tags using [`add_rewrite_tag()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_tag/), after you set the structure.
4. Remember to flush the rewrite rules (i.e. re-save your permalinks) every time you changed the `rewrite` args, including when you simply set `rewrite` to `true` or `false`.

   You can programmatically flush the rules using [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/), however, it should *only be used when necessary*, e.g. upon plugin activation.

   As for the non-programmatic way, simply visit the Permalink Settings admin page without having to click the "save" button.

**Working examples for you**

1. This is for the structure `post-type-1-slug/post-name-year-month-day` where a sample URL might look like `https://example.com/type1/hello-world-2023-02-20/`, and I'm using a custom rewrite tag `%post_date%` for the `year-month-day` part. <sub>(It's up to you if you'd rather use multiple tags, e.g. `%year%`, `%monthnum%`, and `%day%`)</sub>

   ```php
   add_action( 'init', 'my_register_type1_cpt' );
   function my_register_type1_cpt() {
       register_post_type( 'type1', [
           'public'   => true,
           'label'    => 'Type 1',
           'rewrite'  => true,
           // other args
       ] );

       global $wp_rewrite;
       $wp_rewrite->extra_permastructs['type1']['struct'] = 'type1/%type1%-%post_date%';

       // Add a structure tag for dates in either of these form: 2023-02-20 or 2023-2-20.
       add_rewrite_tag( '%post_date%', '(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})' );

       // If you use %year%, %monthnum%, %day% and/or %post_id%, then those are core
       // structure tags in WordPress, hence you do not need to add them manually.
       // However, you still need to manually replace them in the permalink URL!
   }

   add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_type1_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
   function my_type1_post_type_link( $post_link, $post ) {
       if ( $post && 'type1' === $post->post_type ) {
           $post_date = wp_date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $post->post_date ) );

           return str_replace( '%post_date%', $post_date, $post_link );
       }

       return $post_link;
   }
   ```
2. This is for the structure `post-type-2-slug/post-name-id` where a sample URL might look like `https://example.com/type2/hello-world-123/` with `123` being the post ID.

   ```php
   add_action( 'init', 'my_register_type2_cpt' );
   function my_register_type2_cpt() {
       register_post_type( 'type2', [
           'public'   => true,
           'label'    => 'Type 2',
           'rewrite'  => true,
           // other args
       ] );

       global $wp_rewrite;
       $wp_rewrite->extra_permastructs['type2']['struct'] = 'type2/%type2%-%post_id%';
   }

   add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_type2_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
   function my_type2_post_type_link( $post_link, $post ) {
       if ( $post && 'type2' === $post->post_type ) {
           return str_replace( '%post_id%', $post->ID, $post_link );
       }

       return $post_link;
   }
   ```

***Note:** `%type1%` and `%type2%` are the post name/slug and you don't need to replace it manually, i.e. WordPress will do that for you.*

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for that, works perfectly